# Unable to run react native app on android

Tags: android, react-native

I am working on a react native application. The application is working fine on IOS. When i run the app on android i get the following error

```
/node_modules/react-native-image-to-base64/android/src/main/java/com/github/xfumihiro/react_native_image_to_base64/ImageToBase64Package.java:25: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
 @Override


BUILD FAILED in 3s
119 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 118 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I have done all the steps mentioned on the "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started" this link. Can some one please help me

Comment: Are you using react native version 0.60+?
Have you added any configuration or function inside MainActivity?
Have you installed any library before trying to run on android and it was working?
If so, have you checked if it has any additional configuration?

Comment: yes, i am using react native 0.60. No, there is no code in my MainActivity. I have not installed any library. It was and is working on IOS. This is my first try on android. @AndréPinto

Comment: Alright, if you are using react-native-image-to-base64, try to link that library with `react native link react-native-image-to-base64`, if not, try removing node_modules folder and installing it again.
I am saying that because it looks like  react-native-image-to-base64 is an old library and react native 0.60 is very fresh.
Last but not least, you can try to use other libraries to convert image to base 64.